# grep based on timestamp and string pattern

Tags: shell, grep

We need to do some analysis in one of our applications. The log entries have the format:

```
2020-09-21 08:32:06 LoginService.login benchmark total(10003ms) non-login-total(10003ms) login-total0(0ms)[]
```

I wanted to search in this pattern with text ending in `non-login total()` followed by `login-total` in the above mentioned timestamp range, *e.g.* from *08:30* to *08:35*. I tried a few options, but could not get the pattern with the text `non-login` and `login-total` as well. Please provide examples using `zgrep` as its a `.gz` file. Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Comment: There's no real reason for `zgrep` to be used; someone can use `gunzip -c <yourfile | ...anything...`, where `...anything...` can be an awk script or any other tool. Regular expressions aren't great for numeric comparisons except in very limited cases; typically one wants to reach for a more powerful language (of which awk is one).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Can you please provide awk pattern if possible for the above scenario?

Comment: [Using awk to find data matching date range in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710914/using-awk-to-find-data-matching-date-range-in-text-file); [using awk to check between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163257/using-awk-to-check-between-two-dates); [How to filter data between two dates with awk in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275880/how-to-filter-data-between-2-dates-with-awk-in-a-bash-script); &c.

Comment: ...is there a specific technical issue you're stuck on that _isn't_ addressed in any of those links?

Comment: Closing in absence of a response describing a specific problem unique to this question.